# Applescript w/Keynote. Accessing shapes within a slide

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite, keynote

I have a templated Keynote file with some slides and all the slides each have 2 shapes in them. I want to be able to say something like, "hey give me shape 2 of slide 2". The purpose of this, is so that i can add text items directly to that shape. below is the code that I have right now.

I am using the latest Keynote 6.5.2 & Yosemite.

```
  tell application "Keynote"

        activate

        tell document 1

            set anniversary to "Anniversaries"
            set myShape to shape 2 of slide 2
            tell myShape 
                set thisTextItem to make new text item with properties {object text:anniversary}
                #log thisTextItem
                tell thisTextItem
                    set the size of its object text to 144
                    set the color of its object text to "blue"
                end tell

            end tell

        end tell

    end tell
```

I can tell slide 2 by itself and of course i get a big text item for slide 2 with text "Anniversaries" and colored blue but its only slide 2... not within shape 2 of slide 2.

With this code it gives me a pop up error when running the script:

Result:

> error "Keynote got an error: Can’t make or move that element into that
>   container." number -10024

what does this mean? do i not have access to shapes within slides?? Any help/info/examples of setting text within a shape that is within a slide would be beneficial. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the properties of the text in a **shape**, you can't insert a `text item` object in a shape.

```
tell application "Keynote"
    tell document 1
        tell shape 2 of slide 2
            set object text to "Anniversaries"
            tell object text
                set it's size to 44
                set it's color to {0, 0, 65535} -- blue
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: thanks. i figured that for sure after researching. Another question coming up if you want to take a look :)